# Write a function which creates dynamic output based on input array in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function in JavaScript which will take an array of ids as an input and generates corresponding output mentioned below.

Below are the expected cases:

when input array is:

```
ids= [1, 2]
```

expected output is:

```
{
              c: 0,
              query: {
                or: [
                    {  
                      and: [{
                            equals: {
                            field: "emp_id",
                            value: 36,
                        }},
                        {
                            equals: {
                            field: "class_id",
                            value: 1,
                        },
                      }
                        ]

                    },
                    {  
                      and: [{
                            equals: {
                            field: "emp_id",
                            value: 29,
                        }},
                        {
                            equals: {
                            field: "class_id",
                            value: 1,
                        },
                      }
                        ]

                    },
                                        {  
                      and: [{
                            equals: {
                            field: "emp_id",
                            value: 29,
                        }},
                        {
                            equals: {
                            field: "class_id",
                            value: 2,
                        },
                      }
                        ]

                    },
                                        {  
                      and: [{
                            equals: {
                            field: "emp_id",
                            value: 36,
                        }},
                        {
                            equals: {
                            field: "class_id",
                            value: 2,
                        },
                      }
                        ]

                    }
                ]
            },
            a: {}
              };
```

when input array is:

```
ids = [1,2,3]
```

expected output is :

```
 {
      c: 0,
      query: {
        or: [
            {  
              and: [{
                    equals: {
                    field: "emp_id",
                    value: 36,
                }},
                {
                    equals: {
                    field: "class_id",
                    value: 1,
                },
              }
                ]

            },
            {  
              and: [{
                    equals: {
                    field: "emp_id",
                    value: 29,
                }},
                {
                    equals: {
                    field: "class_id",
                    value: 1,
                },
              }
                ]

            },
                                {  
              and: [{
                    equals: {
                    field: "emp_id",
                    value: 29,
                }},
                {
                    equals: {
                    field: "class_id",
                    value: 2,
                },
              }
                ]

            },
                                {  
              and: [{
                    equals: {
                    field: "emp_id",
                    value: 36,
                }},
                {
                    equals: {
                    field: "class_id",
                    value: 2,
                },
              }
                ]

            },
                                                    {  
              and: [{
                    equals: {
                    field: "emp_id",
                    value: 36,
                }},
                {
                    equals: {
                    field: "class_id",
                    value: 3,
                },
              }
                ]

            },
                                                    {  
              and: [{
                    equals: {
                    field: "emp_id",
                    value: 29,
                }},
                {
                    equals: {
                    field: "class_id",
                    value: 3,
                },
              }
                ]

            }
        ]
    },
    a: {}
      };
```

emp_id: 29 and 36 are kind of constant values
which will always be there

Here is what I am trying:

```
   function fc(ids){
for (let i =0 ;i< ids.length;i++){
    let q = {
              c: 0,
              query: {
                or: [
                    {  
                      and: [{
                            equals: {
                            field: "emp_id",
                            value: 36,
                        }},
                        {
                            equals: {
                            field: "class_id",
                            value: ids[i],
                        },
                      }
                        ]

                    },
                    {  
                      and: [{
                            equals: {
                            field: "emp_id",
                            value: 29,
                        }},
                        {
                            equals: {
                            field: "class_id",
                            value: ids[i],
                        },
                      }
                        ]

                    }
                ]
            },
            a: {}
              };
              return q;
}
   }

console.log(fc([1,2,3])); // logs the output with only id:1 not 2!
```

Comment: proper indenting will show you why it does not work as expected. You create q and return it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this could be helpful

```js
const fc = (classIds) => {
  const empIds = [29, 36];
  const arr = [];

  const query = (classId, empId) => {
    return {
      and: [
        {
          equals: {
            field: "emp_id",
            value: empId,
          },
        },
        {
          equals: {
            field: "class_id",
            value: classId,
          },
        },
      ],
    };
  };

  classIds.forEach((cId) => {
    empIds.forEach((eId) => {
      arr.push(query(cId, eId));
    });
  });

  return {
    c: 0,
    query: {
      or: arr,
    },
    a: {},
  };
};

console.log(fc([1, 2, 3]));
```